# manage address book ios iphone

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

I create application, which have to adding, deleting and editing contacts to address book. Everything is fine, but problem is, when application is uninstalled. I cannot keep contacts in address book. I have to deleted all contacts which was added by my application. Is the any way to do this?

I know that is no way to detect when application is uninstalling.

for example my application working… adding contact:

```
+(int)addContactWithName:(NSString*)name withSurname:(NSString *)surname withNoTel:(NSString *) tel{ __block int noKontakt;
if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusDenied ||
    ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted){
```

…

I create contact:

```
int noCon = [self addContactWithName:@"Monika" withSurname:@"Thomas" withNoTel:@"999999"];
```

I’m storing id contact in sqlite and i can delete or update when application working....

I can delete contact:

```
BOOL isDel = [self deleteContactById:(noCon);
```

But when user unistall application contact with id noCon has to be delete. How (or where) to do this?
Thx

Comment: So what is your question? Can you provide a code snippet or example? Thanks

Comment: see the demo .. https://github.com/milanpanchal/MyAddressBookExample

Comment: Thx, I will see this :-)

Comment: This demo not show what I need. I edited my post. Regards